# How to create a squircle shape and fill it with an image using UWP?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xaml, uwp

In an UWP app I need to display some icons with [squircle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squircle) shape and filled with an image.

Applying corner radius to a square doesn't create a squircle, [see](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/resources/images/squircle.gif).

The only way that I found to create squircle shape is using CanvasGeometry like described in this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/parsers/canvaspathgeometry).

I can create a simple squircle like this way:

Xaml:

```
<win2d:CanvasControl
    Width="100"
    Height="100"
    Draw="RenderCanvas_Draw" />
```

Code-behind:

```
private void RenderCanvas_Draw(CanvasControl sender, CanvasDrawEventArgs args)
{
    CanvasGeometry geometry = CanvasPathGeometry.CreateSquircle(sender, 2, 2, 100, 100, 50, 50);
    args.DrawingSession.DrawGeometry(geometry, Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0), 1);
}
```

But I need to fill the squircle with an image and I can't do that.

I can fill the squircle with any color using args.DrawingSession.FillGeometry(...), or I can add an image to CanvasControl using args.DrawingSession.DrawImage(...), but the image occupies a different layer of the squircle.

Does anyone know how to do this or can suggest a solution? Grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fill a geometry with an image using this code

```
private void Canvas_Draw(CanvasControl sender, CanvasDrawEventArgs args)
{
    var geometry = CanvasPathGeometry.CreateSquircle(sender, 0, 0, 100, 100, 50, 50);
    var image = CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync(sender, "color.png").AsTask().Result;
    var brush = new CanvasImageBrush(sender, image);
    args.DrawingSession.FillGeometry(geometry, Vector2.Zero, brush);
}
```